# Android: Problems with executing command in TimerTask when bluetooth connection is reconnected after disconnect

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, bluetooth

**What I want and do:**
I get a bluetooth connection to a paired device when starting the app using Asynctask. --> `new ConnectTask().execute("AMVCarsharingKit");`
This works perfect for the first connection.

Then I have an TimerTask with a Timer which "looks" if a message from the other device was send. If a right message was send the appropriate if will be executed.
This also works fine when the first connection is running.

Now to the important point. I have a BroadcastReceiver for watching the device if it's charging or not. I have this in my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".ChargingOnReceiver" android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

    <receiver android:name=".NotChargingOnReceiver" android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This also works fine.
When it's not charging anymore I disable the bluetooth and close the socket (Look code below). Works fine.

When it's charging again I enable the bluetooth again and start the Activity where the main part will be done. In this Activity I have to reconnect to the other device again (Look at oncreat below). This reconnection works also ( it seems so).

I also receive the messages from the other device without problems. But the Timertask with the many if-terms which looks permanantly for received messages makes problems when the second connection with the other bluetooth device runs. 
I receive the messages correctly and the right if-clause is executed, but most time it doesn't do the commands which are in the if-clause. For example it doesn't go in the right view of the viewflipper. Except the "Call if-clause", this works perfectly all the time.

I really have no idea why this is happening or rather this is not happening.
Has anyone an idea what could be wrong or influence the code?

**BroadcastReceiver when device is NOT charging (snipped code):**

```
   Context applicationContext = CheckVehicleActivity
            .getContextOfApplication();

    //Disable bluetooth
     mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
    } 

    MyApplication app = (MyApplication) applicationContext;
    app.setIsCharging(false);

    mmSocket = app.getmSocket();
    try {
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**BroadcastReceiver when device i charging again (snipped code):**

```
   Context applicationContext = CheckVehicleActivity
            .getContextOfApplication();

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

    MyApplication app = (MyApplication) applicationContext;
    app.setIsCharging(true);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, CheckVehicleActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
```

**onCreate (snipped code):**

```
 // executed when it's charging again
 Boolean isCharging = app.getIsCharging();
 if(isCharging == true){

         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                    new ConnectTask().execute("AMVCarsharingKit");
                    app.setIsCharging(false);

                }
            }, 3000);


    }else{
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                new ConnectTask().execute("AMVCarsharingKit");
                app.setIsCharging(false);

            }
        }, 3000);


    }


    // Cyclic reading of incoming messages
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new ReadTask().execute();
                        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
                        app.setReceivedMsg(receivedMsg);


                        if (receivedMsg.contains(HANDY_ON)) {
                            int id = viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
                            if (id == 0) {
                                showSoftKeyboard();
                            }

                            pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                               wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                               | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
                               wakeLock.acquire();

                            BrightnessUp();

                            receivedMsg = null;
                        }

                        if (receivedMsg.contains(HANDY_OFF)) {


                            // Go to login screen
                            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
                            BrightnessDown();
                            if (wakeLock.isHeld())
                            wakeLock.release();

                            receivedMsg = null;
                        }
                        if (receivedMsg.contains(KEY_OUT)) {
                            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(4);
                            driveModus = true;
                            counterDrive = true;

                            startCounter();
                                            receivedMsg = null;
                        }
                        if (receivedMsg.contains(CALL_ON)) {

                            vfID = viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
                            app.setVfId(vfID);

                            // Register the intent for phone call
                            Intent callIntent = new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345678"));
                            app.setPhone(1);

                            startActivityForResult(callIntent, 1);
                            receivedMsg = null;
                        }
                        if (receivedMsg.contains(FUELCARD_OUT)) {

                            int vfIDf = viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
                            app.setVfId(vfIDf);
                            if(vfIDf == 0){
                                hideSoftKeyboard();
                            }

                            if (driveModus == true) {
                                // Parse the tank PIN
                                int start = receivedMsg.indexOf(".") + 1;
                                int end = receivedMsg.length() - start;

                                tankPIN = String.copyValueOf(
                                        receivedMsg.toCharArray(), start,
                                        end);
                                txtTankID.setText(tankPIN);

                                viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(5);
                                countDownTimer.start();
                                handler();

                            } else if (endModus == true) {
                                fuelNotAllowed
                                        .setText("You already finished your booking. Please put the fuelcard back to the box.");
                                viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(9);
                            } else {
                                viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(9);
                            }

                            receivedMsg = null;

                        }
                        if (receivedMsg.contains(FUELCARD_IN)) {


                            int id = app.getVfId();
                            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(id);
                            if(id==0){
                                showSoftKeyboard();
                            }

                            BrightnessUp();
                            receivedMsg = null;

                        }
                        if (receivedMsg.contains(KEY_IN)) {
                            viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(7);
                            System.out.println("KeyIn-Check: " + receivedMsg);
                            receivedMsg = null;
                        }



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Async-Check: " + receivedMsg);
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);
```

**AsyncTask for the bluetooth connection:**

```
// Get bluetooth connection to the device
private class ConnectTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, BluetoothSocket> {

    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    Set<BluetoothDevice> mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();

            bAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
                    .getDefaultAdapter();

            // Get the all devices which are bonded
            mBluetoothAdapter = bAdapter.getBondedDevices();

            for (BluetoothDevice bc : mBluetoothAdapter) {
                if (bc.getName().indexOf("AMVCarsharingKit") != -1) {
                    UUID uuid = UUID
                            .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // Standard
                                                                                    // SerialPortService
                                                                                    // ID
                    mmDevice = bc;
                    mmSocket = mmDevice
                            .createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

                    mmSocket.connect();
                    BufferedWriter Writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    mmSocket.getOutputStream()));

                    Writer.write(BLUETOOTH_CONNECTED);
                    Writer.flush();

                    app.setmSocket(mmSocket);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return mmSocket;
        } catch(IOException e){
            bAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }   
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask for reading from the device which is connected:**

```
// Read messages which are send from the connected device
private static class ReadTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, BluetoothSocket> {

    @Override
    protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            System.out.println("Test: Before Reader");
            BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(mmSocket.getInputStream()));
            receivedMsg = Reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Reader: " + receivedMsg);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket result) {

    }

}
```